# any() and all() analogues for bitwise operators in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bitwise-operators

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns "Category" and "Total". There can be 4 different categories: A, B, C, D. I am given the cut point value for each category as a dict. I need to exclude all entries with Total more than the corresponding cut point. This works fine:

```
cat = weekly_units['Category']
total = weekly_units['Total']
weekly_units = weekly_units[(cat == 'A') & (total <= cutpoints['A'])
                          | (cat == 'B') & (total <= cutpoints['B'])
                          | (cat == 'C') & (total <= cutpoints['C'])
                          | (cat == 'D') & (total <= cutpoints['D'])]
```

But I find it WET and unpythonic.
Is there a way to write something like this?

```
weekly_units = weekly_units[any([(cat == k) & (total <= v) for k, v in cutpoints.items()])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What you are looking for is [`numpy.logical_or`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html):

```
conditions = [(cat == k) & (total <= v) for k, v in cutpoints.items()]
weekly_units = weekly_units[np.logical_or.reduce(conditions)]
```

Comment: Still thinking if the `reduce` usage is worth it here. GvR tells to avoid `reduce` at almost any situation but in this particular case it is not really bad I guess.

Comment: @SashaTsukanov. Be carful, this isn't Python [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce). This is [`numpy.ufunc.reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html). As such, I don't know GvR's views on specific `numpy` functions.

Comment: Yes I've noticed the difference. Don't know either.

Comment: @SashaTsukanov, In my opinion, if you're using `pandas`, you should be entirely open to using `numpy` functions if they help, since `pandas` relies on `numpy` internally.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. After I tried to apply it to my original code the result turned out to be the most elegant comparing to others' answers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Category` column is actually of `CategoricalDtype`, you can also do:

```
weekly_units[total <= cat.cat.rename_categories(cutpoints).astype(float)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is DRY, simple and explicit:

```
matched = False  # or matched = pd.Series(False, index=weekly_units.index)
for cat, cutpoint in cutpoints.items()
    matched |= ((weekly_units['Category'] == cat) & (weekly_units['Total'] <= cutpoint))
weekly_units = weekly_units[matched]
```

Note that this follows the [official advice](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) to "Use functools.reduce() if you really need it; however, 99 percent of the time an explicit for loop is more readable."

There's also a standard-libary approach using `reduce()`, but as promised, it's less readable:

```
import functools, operator
matched = functools.reduce(
    operator.__or__,  # or lambda x, y: x | y
    (
        (weekly_units['Category'] == cat) & (weekly_units['Total'] <= cut)
        for cat, cut in cutpoints.items()
    )
)
weekly_units = weekly_units[matched]
```

Comment: I like the idea of not using reduce and writing `weekly_units['Category']` and `weekly_units['Total']` explicitly, so I accept your answer. Since in the original code I need `matched` to be combined with other conditions I'll write separate inner function to compute `matched`

Comment: Is there any significant difference between using `operator.__or__` and `numpy.logical_or`?

Comment: @SashaTsukanov You beat me to it on the parentheses! I think they are required around each (in)equality test but not around the whole expression. To answer your question about `__or__`: Python converts `|`  or `operator.__or__` into a call to `pd.Series.__or__`, which has code that calls `operator.or_()` (identical to `operator.__or__`) with ndarrays for the two series. `operator.or_` just uses the Python `|` operator on the ndarrays, which passes them to `np.ndarray.__or__`. I'm not sure how closely `np.ndarray.__or__` is related to `np.logical_or`, but they should do roughly the same thing.

Comment: I launched the script without parenthesis around the whole expression and it really worked the same.
I have one more question. First you assign `matched` to `False` and then it becomes a mask-like series containing a boolean for each `weekly_units` row. Does this work because of numpy broadcasting?

Comment: Really like your idea but in my opinion the last aspect is what makes the code not too obvious nor explicit

Comment: @SashaTsukanov The initial `False` is treated like most numpy or pandas operations between a scalar and a vector/series — the scalar automatically gets used with all elements of the series. I agree that it’s a little jarring that the code promotes `matched` from a scalar to a series. On the other hand, this avoids having to add special code to the loop for the first pass (something `reduce()` handles automatically). An alternative would be to initialize with `matched = pd.Series(False, index=weekly_units.index)`.